# Список одинаковых инстансов? Как исправить?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп

Помогите поправить код, почему-то в списке **slices** одинаковые инстансы **slices[0], ..., slices[6]** 
Как понимаю проблема в цикле

```
while y_beg + 50 < 2*r - gap_down:
    points = init_slice(y_beg, y_end)
    slice_instance = Slice(points)
    print("instance:", slice_instance)
    slices.append(slice_instance)
    # Go to next slice
    y_beg += 50 + gap
    y_end = y_beg + 50
```

Вот весь код

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import math

x_c = 320
y_c = r = 240
gap = 10
gap_up = 10
gap_down = 10

def chord(a):
    return math.sqrt(r*r - a*a)

def init_slice(y_beg, y_end):
    # upper chord
    x1_beg = x_c - chord(r - y_beg)
    a = (x1_beg, y_beg)
    x1_end = x_c + chord(r - y_beg)
    b = (x1_end, y_beg)
    # lower chord
    x2_beg = x_c - chord(r - y_end)
    c = (x2_beg, y_end)
    x2_end = x_c + chord(r - y_end)
    d = (x2_end, y_end)
    return [a, b, c, d]


class Slice():

    def __init__(self, points):
        self.pointA = points[0]
        self.pointB = points[1]
        self.pointC = points[2]
        self.pointD = points[3]

    # string representation of an object
    def __repr__(self):
        return ' '.join(map(str, points))


y_beg = gap_up
y_end = y_beg + 50

# Empty list
slices = []

while y_beg + 50 < 2*r - gap_down:
    points = init_slice(y_beg, y_end)
    slice_instance = Slice(points)
    print("instance:", slice_instance)
    slices.append(slice_instance)
    #slices.extend(Slice(points))

    # Go to next slice
    y_beg += 50 + gap
    y_end = y_beg + 50       


#print(slices)

print(slices[6] is slices[0], slices[0])
print(slices[6] is slices[1], slices[1])
print(slices[6] is slices[2], slices[2])
print(slices[6] is slices[3], slices[3])
```

Вывод следующий (выведу лишь первую точку, по факту пишет 4 точки):
`instance: (251.44345399598956, 10)`
`instance: (150.58925653902583, 70)`
`instance: (106.69270992298459, 130)`
`instance: (85.26610811388994, 190)`
`instance: (80.20842383436403, 250)`
`instance: (90.43519433502007, 310)`
`instance: (118.25758998167984, 370)`

и такое

`False (118.25758998167984, 370)`
`False (118.25758998167984, 370)`
`False (118.25758998167984, 370)`
`False (118.25758998167984, 370)`

Comment: Поправьте отступы в примере, а то вы видимо скопировали неаккуратно и код теперь не запускается. Ещё желательно вывод принтов добавить, чтобы было проще разбираться не уходя далеко от вопроса

Comment: Добавьте что выводит ваш код.

Comment: Ошибка тут `return ' '.join(map(str, points))`. `points` у вас снаружи инстанса.

Comment: @andreymal, отступы поправлены

Comment: @ insolor, вывод добавлен

Comment: @extrn, на счёт `points` согласен, не заметил что-то. Тем не менее инстансы различные (я в конце их добавил), а именно они и добавляются в список `slices`, тогда возникает вопрос: если инстансы различные и они добавляются в список, то почему элементы этого списка одинаковые?

Comment: @Tim `slices[6] is slices[0] == False` говорит, что инстансы разные (не обязательно по содержимому) и ему можно верить. а вывод на экран врет, потому, что задействует `__repr__`, который выводит один и тот же points для всех, отсюда и одинаковый вывод.

Comment: @extrn, строка `slice_instance = Slice(points)` в цикле даёт разные инстансы по содержимому, вот они: `instance: (251.44345399598956, 10)` `instance: (150.58925653902583, 70)` `instance: (106.69270992298459, 130)` `instance: (85.26610811388994, 190)` `instance: (80.20842383436403, 250)` `instance: (90.43519433502007, 310)` `instance: (118.25758998167984, 370)`. Затем по коду `slices.append(slice_instance)`, но на выходе не эти 7 инстансов, а 7 раз последний инстанс. Ну как такое возможно? Почему repr не врет в `print("instance:", slice_instance)` и врет в `print(slices[0])` ?

Comment: @Tim ДА, может. Потому, что в том цикле меняется и `points`, а вот дальше он уже не меняется. Исправьте наконец `__repr__`, и увидите.

Comment: @ extr, кажется доходить теперь начинает, но исправить не удается...  `class Slice():

    def __init__(self, points):
        self.arr = (points[0], points[1], points[2], points[3], points[4])

    def __repr__(self):
        return ' '.join(map(str, self.arr))` выдаёт ошибку `list index out of rang`

Comment: @Tim `points[4]` лишняя. `self.arr = points` будет достаточно

Comment: @ extrn, красиво, спасибо, всё работает!

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в методе **repr** класса Slice. У объектов класса нет поля `points`, поэтому он берет последний элемент, переданный в конструктор с этим именем.

Одно из возможных решений выглядит так:

```py
class Slice():

    def __init__(self, points):
        self.pointA = points[0]
        self.pointB = points[1]
        self.pointC = points[2]
        self.pointD = points[3]
        # added new field
        self.points = points

    # string representation of an object
    def __repr__(self):
                         #added (self.)
        return ' '.join(map(str, self.points))
```